# como exibir imagens com xsl com a src da img do arquivo xml

Tags: html, xml, xpath, xslt

Eu tenho por exemplo o codigo XSL:

```
<xsl:for-each select="//*">
  <xsl:for-each select="imagem">
    <img>
      <xsl:attribute name="src">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </xsl:attribute>
    </img>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
```

tenho por exemplo seguinte codigo xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<imagens>
<imagem>
    <png id="1">img1.png</png>
    <png id="2">img2.png</png>
    <png id="3">img3.png</png>
    <png id="4">img4.png</png>
    <png id="5">img5.png</png>
</imagem>
<imagem>
    <png id="1">img6.png</png>
    <png id="2">img7.png</png>
    <png id="3">img8.png</png>
    <png id="4">img9.png</png>
    <png id="5">img10.png</png>
</imagem>
```

Estou tentando fazer que esse codigo se tranforme em algo assim:

```
<img src="img1.png"><img src="img2.png"><!--E assim por diante-->
```

Mas ele fica assim:

```
<img src="img1.pngimg2.pngimg3.pngimg4.pngimg5.png">
```

alguém ae tem alguma ideia de como resolver?

Answer (score 1):

O ideal é selecionar o elemento que você quer usando um template que será chamado recursivamente enquanto os nós do documento são processados. O documento XSL abaixo faz exatamente o que você quer sem precisar usar `for-each`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="html"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="png">
        <img src="{.}" />
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Resultado:

```
<img src="img1.png"><img src="img2.png"> ... <img src="img10.png">
```

Comment: Vlw era assim mesmo. só não dou +1 pra resposta pq to sem reputação kkk

Answer (score 0):

Experimente o seguinte:

```
  <xsl:for-each select="//**">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="imagem"/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <xsl:element name="imagem">
          <xsl:attribute name="src">
            <xsl:value-of select="png"/>
          </xsl:attribute>
          <xsl:attribute name="align">left</xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:element>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </xsl:for-each>
</table>
```

Comment: Ainda não é isso. Gerou um codigo parecido com com img1.pngimg2.png... sem as imagens e o resto as img aparecerão coma src vazias

Comment: eu tentei algo assim e quase deu certo so faltou a tabulação e a kda trecho de codigo executado da imagem do xml gera um erro

Comment: <table border="1"><xsl:for-each select="//*"><tr><xsl:element name="imagem"><td><img><xsl:attribute name="src"><xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:attribute></img></td></xsl:element></xsl:for-each></table>